# Write the output of socket module into a file

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to get the hostname of my computer and then write it to a file.  This is what I've got so far, but its not working, where am I going wrong?

```
def testing():
    os.mkdir("zzzdirectory")
    os.chdir("zzzdirectory")
    fo=open("testfolder.txt", "wb")
    fo.write("this is the first line of the file\n")
    s=socket.gethostname()
    fo.write(s)
    fo.close()

testing()
```

Comment: you need to give more details, in what way is not working, what error do you get

Comment: Thats weird, sorry, it looks like its cut the first 3 or 4 lines of my post for some reason :/ .....   It just wont print.  All is get is the "this is the first line of file\n" and i want the next line to be the hostname of my machine.  It seems the socket.gethostname() line is just skipped over, im thinking maybe save it to a %s and then print ?

Comment: Someone edited your post removing irrelevant details hence the missing lines. What we need are relevant details like what error message or incorrect output you are getting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are not *importing* the required modules. Also, you should try & use the `with` statement for file handling. It is more pythonic.

```
import os
import socket

def testing():
    os.mkdir("zzzdirectory")
    os.chdir("zzzdirectory")
    s=socket.gethostname()
    with open("testfolder.txt", "wb") as fo:
        fo.write("this is the first line of the file\n")
        fo.write(s)

testing()
```

Comment: ah! thankyou, i searched for ages trying to find an answer.  Thanks for your/everybodys help.  Greatly appreciated.

Comment: @AshishNitinPatil, Why do you recommend to use `writelines`? It is useful only when you write sequence of strings. A string object could be used because it is treated a sequence of single character strings. But `write` is enough if the argument is a string object.

Comment: Well, the question was not very clear, so I just gave a suggestion for *writelines* adding the 2 import statements. My only aim was to avoid the `\n` (which I stupidly didn't even remove)

Comment: @alistair mentioned in [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20026871/write-the-output-of-socket-module-into-a-file/20027068#comment29823647_20026871) that he wanted them on 2 separate lines, so the suggestion. :/

Comment: Oh, I was not aware of that. The method name is quite delusional.

Comment: Updated accordingly. Guess, me might never know what the problem was!

Comment: Thanks for such kindness & careful guidance!

Comment: Which should always be the case :)